# Edit nodes from command line

Tags: nodes, drush

I am looking for a way to manage nodes from command line.

I am aware of drush and [drush-entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity), and it can do the job in a way, but I thought it could be easier having the nodes stored in files (instead of a database) to version control them with git.

I there a way to do this? (Maybe a module or a drush script)